# Thread name in Akka actor logging regarding PinnedDispatcher

Tags: scala, logging, akka

I am coding an application with Akka v2.5.23. The application involves below actors:

- An router actor class named CalculatorRouter
- An routee actor class named Calculator

I've configured a PinnedDispatcher when creating Calculator actor and put `log.info` in this actor class's receive method. I've expected to see in the log file the thread name field to contain `pinned`. However, the thread name field is `default-dispatcher`. I've searched in the log file and found that all the thread name with respect to this `log.info` to be `default-dispatcher`. Is there something wrong with my code?

Log file snippet:

```
09:49:25.116 [server-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-14] INFO  handler.Calculator $anonfun$applyOrElse$3 92 - akka://server/user/device/$a/$a Total calc received
```

Follows are the code snippets:

```
class CalculatorRouter extends Actor with ActorLogging {
    var router = {
        val routees = Vector.fill(5) {
            val r = context.actorOf(Props[Calculator].withDispatcher("calc.my-pinned-dispatcher"))
            context.watch(r)
            ActorRefRoutee(r)
        }
        Router(SmallestMailboxRoutingLogic(), routees)
    }

    def receive = {
        case w:  Calc => router.route(w, sender)
        case Terminated(a) =>
            router.removeRoutee(a)
            val r = context.actorOf(Props[Calculator].withDispatcher("calc.my-pinned-dispatcher"))
            context.watch(r)
            router = router.addRoutee(r)
    }
}
```

The calc.my-pinned-dispatcher is configured as follows:

```
  calc.my-pinned-dispatcher {
    executor="thread-pool-executor"
    type=PinnedDispatcher
  }
```

Source code of class calculator as follows:

```
class Calculator extends Actor with ActorLogging {
    val w = new UdanRemoteCalculateTotalBalanceTime

    def receive = {
        case TotalCalc(fn, ocvFilepath, ratedCapacity, battCount) ⇒

                log.info(s"${self.path} Total calc received")
                Try{
                    w.CalculateTotalBalanceTime(1, fn, ocvFilepath, ratedCapacity)
                } match {
                    case Success(t) ⇒
                        val v = t.getIntData
                        sender.!(Calculated(v))(context.parent)
                    case Failure(e) ⇒ log.error(e.getMessage)
                }
    }
}

object Calculator {
    sealed trait Calc
    final case class TotalCalc(filename: String, ocvFilepath: String, ratedCapacity: String, batteryCount: Int) extends Calc
}
```

logback.xml

```
<configuration debug="true">
   <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
        <!-- reset all previous level configurations of all j.u.l. loggers -->
        <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
    </contextListener>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/var/log/app.log</file>
        <append>true</append>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
          <!-- daily rollover -->
              <fileNamePattern>/var/log/app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>

              <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history capped at 3GB total size -->
              <maxHistory>100</maxHistory>
              <totalSizeCap>30000MB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} %M %L - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNCFILE" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <queueSize>500</queueSize>
        <includeCallerData>true</includeCallerData>
    </appender>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} %M %L - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>


    <logger name="application" level="DEBUG"/>
    <root level="INFo">
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNCFILE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

'20 Mar 4 Update

Thanks @anand-sai. After I put `akka.loggers-dispatcher = "calc.my-pinned-dispatcher"` in conf file, I've got `my-pinned-dispatcher-xx` as the thread name in every line of the log file. I thought the thread name should indicate the thread wherein actor Calculator's `receive` method is executing, in this case, something similar to `'pinned-dispatcher-xx'` as the thread was obtained by a pinned dispatcher per my configuration. Now it proves that it indicates the thread obtained by logger's dispatcher. If this is the case, how to log the thread name for an actor's message handler code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution is to add `akka.loggers-dispatcher` in your `application.conf`

```
calc.my-pinned-dispatcher {
    executor="thread-pool-executor"
    type=PinnedDispatcher
  }
akka.loggers-dispatcher = "calc.my-pinned-dispatcher"
```

If you search for `logger-dispatcher` in the [default configuration](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/configuration-reference.html) of akka, you will find the value to be "akka.actor.default-dispatcher` and we need to override this config as shown above.

**EDIT**

ActorLogging is asynchronous. When you log using ActorLogging, it sends a message to the logging actor, which by default runs on the default dispatcher. Logback logs the thread that called it, which will be the ActorLogging actor's thread, not your actor's thread.In order to achieve this goal, there is a so-called **Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC) that captures the `akka source`(The path of the actor in which the logging was performed )** , **`source thread`( the thread in which the logging was performed)** and much more in which the logging was performed.

As given in the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/logging.html#mdc-values-from-akka-internal-logging):

> Since the logging is done asynchronously the thread in which the
>   logging was performed is captured in MDC with attribute name
>   `sourceThread`.
>
> The path of the actor in which the logging was performed is available
>   in the MDC with attribute name `akkaSource`.
>
> The actor system name in which the logging was performed is available
>   in the MDC with attribute name `sourceActorSystem`, but that is
>   typically also included in the `akkaSource` attribute.
>
> The address of the actor system, containing host and port if the
>   system is using cluster, is available through `akkaAddress`.
>
> For typed actors the log event timestamp is taken when the log call
>   was made but for Akka’s internal logging as well as the classic actor
>   logging is asynchronous which means that the timestamp of a log entry
>   is taken from when the underlying logger implementation is called,
>   which can be surprising at first. If you want to more accurately
>   output the timestamp for such loggers, use the MDC attribute
>   `akkaTimestamp`. Note that the MDC key will not have any value for a
>   typed actor.

Let me know if it helps!!

Comment: After put akka.loggers-dispatcher = "calc.my-pinned-dispatcher" in conf file, I've got `my-pinned-dispatcher-xx` as the thread name in every line of the log file.

Comment: Thanks for your edit and referring to the documentation. I've put sourceThread in the config file and it works as I expected. The log file now has `pinned-dispatcher-xx` as the thread name for the log invocation in the actor associated with a PinnedDispatcher.